# Blurry vision after exercise?

Tags: cardio, health

I've noticed that after I do some heavy cardio my vision will sometimes get blurry.  The blurriness usually occurs about 15-30 minutes after I exercise and then lasts for 15-30 minutes and is usually confined to one spot in my field of vision.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Should I be concerned or is this a common thing?

Update:

Type of cardio - pretty much anything (but not every time).  Typically bike riding, running or body pump class

```
Age - 30
Height - 6'5"
Weight - 200lbs
```

Comment: What cardio are you doing? What age, weight...etc are you? Something like this you should prob talk to your doctor about.

Comment: What's your blood pressure?  Do you know your resting heart rate, or your heart rate right when you finjsh exercising?  Have you checked it recently?  After exercise?  I've sometimes had "throbbing vision" right after extremely strenuous exercise.  But I'm pretty sure that if what you're experiencing is related to a high pulse rate or high blood pressure, then it's very unhealthy, and you might want to see a doctor.

Comment: That is a question for your doctor.

Comment: Any other symptoms along with the blurred vision? perhaps headache, numbness in extremities, for nausea?

Comment: No nothing like that.

Comment: I get servere headaches, dizzyness, blurred vision and nausea after workouts. I have worked out for 8 years now, run, swim and lift. I just take it as over-working myself but idk i usually feel the effects for a good hour after the workout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think blurry vision and/or dizziness are quite common when exercising. In [this article](http://www.livestrong.com/article/482531-blurry-vision-during-exercise/) there are some common causes given for it.

> A common cause of blurry vision during exercise is low blood pressure, or hypotension. A number of factors can bring this on, but those common to exercise include dehydration, allergic reactions or a lack of nutrients in the body. Exercise can also cause or exacerbate blurred vision in people with pigmentary glaucoma, the Monroe Family Eyecare website advises. If you are pregnant, blurred vision could indicate preeclampsia and may warn of your baby's struggle to get all the blood it needs to survive.

I too have a somewhat blurry vision and 'dizziness' which can be described as a 'high'. But this fades within a minute or so. You also said that the blurry vision lasts longer than this. This should raise some concerns and I strongly suggest to get this looked at by a professional.